# Add XML file to ZIP

Tags: c#, xml, telerik, zip

### Issue

---

I have been given an old piece of code (5+ years) and have been adding functioanlity to the application. I have come across an issue and that the XML file is not correctly getting added to the ZIP. When I check the ZIP after the XML file appear but with 0 data.

### Code

---

So I create my XML and add the correct data into the file:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream doc = localStorage.OpenFile(xmlFile, FileMode.Open))
{
     //Add code to populate XML file. Works fine.
}
```

Then I open XML and create a ZIP and I am trying to add the XML to the ZIP:

**NOTE:** There is a line under '*ZipPackage*' that says "*The class has been deprecated*"

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = localStorage.OpenFile(xmlFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream zipStream = localStorage.CreateFile(zipFile))
    {
        using (ZipPackage zipPackage = ZipPackage.Create(zipStream))
        {
            zipPackage.AddStream(fileStream, xmlFile, ZipCompression.Deflate64, DateTime.Now);
            zipPackage.Close(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Then finally I copy the bytes to the file:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream zipStream = localStorage.OpenFile(zipFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    fileData = new byte[zipStream.Length];
    zipStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
    zipStream.Close();
}
```

When I debug this the XML file that is created has all the information in the file that is needed. When it is added to the ZIP it looses all the data.

EDIT: The '*ZipPackage*' is from Telerik and I am using Windows 7. I am up for changing the way the file is compressed to get it to work.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I am using Telerik ZipPackage but also am up for changing this if other things work better.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework are you targeting?  The ability to create Zip files has been built in since 4.5.

Comment: If you can't use the built in bits, I'd suggest reading the docs.  Telerik say [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radziplibrary/changes-and-backwards-compatibility/backward-compatibility.html) that `ZipPackage` is obsolete and you should use `ZipArchive` and there's a [getting started](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radziplibrary/gettingstarted.html) for using that.